# How Do I use a for-loop within a .sh file and kill the process once the search String is found and exit

Tags: shell, scripting

I am a newbie to shell scripting.I have a requirement to run a .sh file from my java program.The .sh file script will search for a caseId in the threadJob logs( example: job_100 to job_250).This should be run in a for-loop by just changing the JOBNO variable for every iteration.The below script is working fine  if I passed a caseId to search within one threadJob log.

I have to stop the execution and kill the 
process inside the script file itself once the caseId found or while exiting(not found).I tried kill -9 command but not working.I hope someone can help me on this.Thanks in advance.

script_file.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
JOBNO="$1"
BATCHDATE="$2"
CASEID="$3"
PID=find ../var/batch/"$JOBNO"/log -name 
$JOBNO*BatchEdbc.$BATCHDATE*.log"|xargs grep -r -B 3 "$CASEID"
```

my Java program:

```
public static String getLogForCaseId(String caseId, String batchJobName, java.sql.Date batchDate)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = null;
    String cmd[] = { "/bin/bash", "/home/GeneralUser/WorkSpace_1711/batch/src/main/resources/scripts/script_file.sh",
            batchJobName, batchDate, caseId };
    try {
        proc = rt.exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        String caseLogline;
        while ((caseLogline = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb2.append(caseLogline + "-");
            }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException("Error when executing the command", e);
    } finally {
        proc.destroy();
    }
    return sb2.toString();
}
```

Comment: How do you plan to get **two** job numbers of "*example: job_100 to job_250*" from `JOBNO="$1"`? Are there always `151` jobs you want to kill (e.g. `100-250` [inclusive])?

Comment: I think I can use a for loop to generate the job numbers(numbers from 100 to 250) and concatenate with the jobString.For example, I can pass "PX00E" from my program instead of actual jobNumber and concatenate with the number generated.so I will be getting "PX00E100" as a job number within the for-loop .

Comment: I get how to do it, but in order to help you I need to know how you want to do it. That's why I asked, "Will it always be `151` jobs?". You can simply generate the names in a POSIX compliant way with `for i in seq 100 250; do echo "something with file_$1"; done`, or in a bash (and most shells) way with a C-style loop `for ((i = 100; i <= 250; i++)); do echo "something with file_$1"; done`. So my question is "will it always be `100-250`?"

Comment: Yes,It will be always 100 to 250.These are thread jobs which will process the records which are inserted into a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine some command to get PID of your running process.
For example, in case I run selenium server java process on my server and when I execute command `ps aux | grep 'selenium'`, I will get:

```
java -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -port 4444 -role hub
```

Based on output of ps command, I construct new command to get exactly PIP of selenium process:

```
kill $(ps aux | grep '[s]elenium-server-standalone' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Modify this follow your case.